# Missing operator<< but it's there

Tags: c++, templates

Int this class where operator<< is defined (see code) while trying to compile it with gcc 4.6.1 I'm getting following **error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << a'**. What's going on?

```
template<class Int_T = int, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::min(),
                            typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::max()>
class Int
{
Int_T data_;  

Int_T get_data()const
{
return data_;
}

};  
//Here is this operator defined
template<class Int_T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Int<Int_T, Best_Fit<Int_T>::type, Best_Fit<Int_T>::type>& obj)
{
    out << obj.get_data();
    return out;
}
```

where Best_Fit looks like:

```
#ifndef BEST_FIT_H_INCLUDED
#define BEST_FIT_H_INCLUDED


struct Signed_Type
{
    typedef long long type;
};

struct Unsigned_Type
{
    typedef unsigned long long type;
};

template<bool Cond, class First, class Second>
struct if_
{
    typedef typename First::type type;
};

template<class First, class Second>
struct if_<false,First,Second>
{
    typedef typename Second::type type;
};

template<class Int_T>
struct Best_Fit
{//evaluate it lazily ;)
    typedef typename if_<std::is_signed<Int_T>::value,Signed_Type,Unsigned_Type>::type type;
};

#endif // BEST_FIT_H_INCLUDED
```

edit:

```
#include <iostream>  
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Int<signed char,1,20> a(30);

    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with main?

Comment: That's some happy template magic. You are wrapping standard numeric types, aren't you? If it's no secret, what is your goal? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Septagram of course this isn't a secret  - my goal is to create safe int class. I'm doing this to practice template (meta) programming

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas When I add typename I'm getting compiler error telling me that value/type mismatch has "come to town"

Comment: @smallB: I think I have answered your question below, and that was one part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template has three arguments, a type, and two constants of a known *best fit* type, but your templated `operator<<` takes an instantiation of the template with *three* types.

```
template<class Int_T = int, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range
                                     = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::min(), // constant!
                            typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range
                                     = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::max()  // constant!
        >
class Int
//...
template<class Int_T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, 
                         const Int<Int_T, 
                                   Best_Fit<Int_T>::type, // type!
                                   Best_Fit<Int_T>::type  // type!
                         >& obj)
```

I usually recommend that operator overloads of class templates are defined inside the class definition (use `friend` to define a free function in that context) for this particular reason, it is trivial to get the types right inside the class template, and easy to fail outside of it. There are a couple other differences (like the fact that if the operator is defined inside the class then it will only be accessible through ADL --unless you also decide to declare it outside)

```
template<class Int_T = int, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range
                                     = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::min(), // constant!
                            typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range
                                     = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::max()  // constant!
        >
class Int {
   friend                  // allows you to define a free function inside the class
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, 
                             Int const & obj ) {  // Can use plain Int to refer to this 
                                                  // intantiation. No need to redeclare
                                                  // all template arguments
       return out << obj.get_data();
   }
};
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should declare it as a class member? But is there a way to declare it as a "free standing" fnc?

Comment: I have edited the answer, the simplest thing you can do is define the operator inside the class scope. Or you can try and fix the template. Not tried, so no guarantees: `template <typename Int_T, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range> std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, Int< Int_T, Min_Range, Max_Range> const & obj ) {...`

Comment: Not as a *member* function, but declare and define it *inside* the class scope as a free function. You can do that with the *friend* keyword: `class X { friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& o, X const & x ) { return o; }` declares and defines a free-standing function in the enclosing namespace that can only be found through ADL. All identifiers present inside the `X` type can be used directly, as we are inside the class context while defining the function.

Comment: I have it already defined in class scope. I'll try you're template and let you know.

Comment: I have edited with how it would be *defined* **inside** the class scope, where you do not even need the template part (nor want, adding a new set of arguments in a template there would provide with different semantics.