# Will this static_assert ever be triggered?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

```
template<class Int_T,class Integral,typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range,
    typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range>
auto operator+(Integral left,const Int<Int_T,Min_Range,Max_Range>& right)
    ->Int<decltype(left + right.get_data())>
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Integral>::value,"Non integral type is not allowed.");
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Int_T>::value,"Non integral type is not allowed.");
    auto data = left + right.get_data();
    Int<decltype(left + right.get_data())> result(data);
    return result;
}
```

The point is that I don't think that those two static_assert**s** will ever be triggered - even if one tries too.
So what's the answer to this Q?

Comment: I don't see why not, you *could* come up with a class which satisfies the constraints (`Best_Fit` and `Int` - whatever they are), but fails `is_integral`...

Comment: I think it is impossible to answer without definitions for `Int<>`, `Best_Fit<>` because anyone of those could trigger SFINAE

Comment: @sehe && Kerrek sorry for not providing those defs. Please find them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790524/missing-operator-but-its-there

Comment: @KerrekSB Could be promoted to a larger type, e.g. if `Integral` has a higher rank than `Int_T`.

Comment: @LucDanton: Oh, yes, I misread that. Never mind!

Comment: What is your real question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct dummy {
    operator int() const
    { return 0; }
};

// Where rhs has appropriate type
dummy() + rhs;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string x;
Int<int, 3, 5> i;

auto z = x + i;
```

Triggered it.

Comment: That's odd. I would have expected the `decltype(left + right.get_data())` to SFINAE out `operator+`. And in fact I can't reproduce your finding on my copy of GCC.

Comment: Well, try any type that is convertible or addable to `int` and even SFINAE won't help you. Eg. `double`.

Comment: `std::string` is not such a type.

Comment: No it's not, and it looks like GCC will SFINAE `std::string` out while MSVC doesn't do SFINAE for this case. Even on GCC, however, a type like `double` will allow addition to an `int` while not passing `is_integral`.